# Show $\arg\max E_Y[\min(f(x),Y)]\le \arg\max f(x)$

Tags: optimization

Suppose $f(x)$ is a concave function and $Y$ is a random variable. What is the relationship between $\arg\max E_Y[\min(f(x),Y)]$ and $\arg\max f(x)$. I feel the former is less than or equal to the latter, but do not have a clue to show it.

Comment: Are you asking about $\max$ or $\arg\max$?

Comment: @VHarisop   arg max

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything you could say about the argmax, but your conclusion is definitely true for the max.